# How many triangles are formed by $n$ chords of a circle?

Tags: combinatorics, polygons

This is a homework problem I have to solve, and I think I might be misunderstanding it. I'm translating it from Polish word for word.

> $n$ points are placed on a circle, and all the chords whose endpoints they are are drawn. We assume that no three chords intersect at one point.
>
> a) How many parts do the chords dissect the disk?
>
> b) How many triangles are formed whose sides are the chords or their fragments?

I think the answer to a) is $2^n$. But I couldn't find a way to approach b), so I calculated the values for small $n$ and asked OEIS about them. I got [A006600](http://oeis.org/A006600). And it appears that there is no known formula for all $n$. [This page](http://www.mathematik.uni-bielefeld.de/~sillke/SEQUENCES/triangle_counting) says that

> $\text{triangles}(n) = P(n) - T(n)$
>
> where $P(n)$ is the number of triangles for a convex n-gon in general
>   position. This means there are no three diagonal through one point
>   (except on the boundary). (There are no degenarate corners.)
>   This number is easy to calculate as:
>
> $$P(n) = {n\choose 3} + 4{n\choose 4} + 5{n\choose5} + {n\choose6}
>        = {n(n-1)(n-2)(n^3 + 18 n^2 - 43 n + 60)\over720}$$
>
> The four terms count the triangles in the following manner [CoE76]:
>
> $n\choose3$: Number of trianges with 3 corners at the border.
>
> $4{n\choose4}$: Number of trianges with 2 corners at the border.
>
> $5{n\choose5}$: Number of trianges with 1 corners at the border.
>
> $n\choose6$: Number of trianges with 0 corners at the border.
>
> $T(n)$ is the number of triple-crossings (this is the number of
>   triples of diagonals which are concurrent) of the regular $n$-gon.
>   It turns out that such concurrences cannot occur for n odd, and,
>   except for obvious cases, can only occur for $n$ divisible by $6$.
>   Among other interesting results, Bol [Bol36] finds values of n
>   for which $4$, $5$, $6$, and $7$ diagonals are concurrent and shows that
>   these are the only possibilities (with the center for exception).
>
> The function $T(n)$ for $n$ not divisible by $6$ is:
>
> $$T(n) = {1\over8}n(n-2)(n-7)[2|n] + {3\over4}n[4|n].$$
>
> where $[k|n]$ is defined as $1$ if $k$ is a divisor of $n$ and otherwise $0$.
>
> The intersection points need not lie an any of lines of symmetry of
>   the $2m$-gon, e. g. for $n=16$ the triple intersection of $(0,7),(1,12),(2,14)$.

If I understand the text correctly, it doesn't give a general formula for $T(n)$. Also I've found a statement somewhere else that some mathematician wasn't able to give a general formula solving this problem. I haven't found a statement that it is still an open problem, but it looks like it to me.

So am I just misunderstanding the problem, or misunderstanding what I've found on the web, or maybe it is indeed a very hard problem? It's the beginning of the semester, our first homework, and it really scares me.

Comment: The answer is not $2^{n-1}$. However, this is a wonderful example of a sequence which is not "obvious". That is, when you give me a sequence of, say $n$ numbers, it is possible to give an arbitrary number as the $n+1^{th}$ member of the sequence *and back it up with a valid reason*. For example, this sequence goes 2, 4, 8, 16, 31... So if a friend gives you the sequence 2, 4, 8, 16 and asks you what comes next you can say "31" and give them a perfectly logical reason as to why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to a) isn't $2^n$. It isn't even $2^{n-1}$, which is probably what you meant. Draw the case $n=6$, carefully, and count the regions.

As for $T(n)$, the number of triple-crossings, the problem statement specifically says there are no triple-crossings.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what "concurrent" meant! Thank you very much!