# Number of triangles formed by all chords between $n$ points on a circle

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, circles, triangles, combinations

> We have $n$ point on the circumference of a circle. We draw all chords between these points. No three chords are concurrent.
>
> How many triangles exist that their apexes could be on circumference of the circle or intersection points of chords and side of triangles is on chords?

Things I have done so far:

There are four situations:
[image]

- situation #$1$:all points on circumference.
- situation #$2$:two points on the circumference, one intersection point.
- situation #$3$:one point on the circumference, two intersection points.
- situation #$4$:three intersection points.

Situation #1 is easily countable. ${n \choose 3}$

For other situations, I can't find a way for counting them.

Answer (according to answer key): $${n \choose 3} + 4{n \choose 4} + 5{n \choose 5} + {n \choose 6}$$

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many triangles are formed by $n$ chords of a circle?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313489/how-many-triangles-are-formed-by-n-chords-of-a-circle)

Comment: Or this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439093

Comment: @Alpha,the OP in this question math.stackexchange.com/questions/313489 don't have problems in figuring out why number of triangles are ${n \choose 3}$+$4{n \choose 4}$+$5{n \choose 5}$+${n \choose 6}$.and the second one you posted is not about combinations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Situation $2$:

For each selection of any $4$ points on the circumference, you can draw the diagram you have. The line segment that joins the adjacent circumference points, could instead join any of the $4$ pairs of adjacent circumference points, so we have $4$ different triangles for each choice of $4$ circumference points.

There are $\binom{n}{4}$ ways to choose the $4$ points, so Situation $2$ contributes:

$\qquad4 \binom{n}{4}$ triangles.

Situation $3$:

For each selection of any $5$ points on the circumference, you can draw the diagram you have. You could choose any of these $5$ points to be a vertex of a Situation $3$ triangle, so we have $5$ different triangles for each choice of $5$ circumference points.

There are $\binom{n}{5}$ ways to choose the $5$ points, so Situation $3$ contributes:

$\qquad5 \binom{n}{5}$ triangles.

Situation $4$:

For each selection of any $6$ points on the circumference, you can draw the diagram you have. There is only one way to construct that internal triangle given these $6$ circumference points.

There are $\binom{n}{6}$ ways to choose the $6$ points, so Situation $4$ contributes:

$\qquad \binom{n}{6}$ triangles.